# how to delete a xml node if it has no child nodes

Tags: php, xml, nodes

I am creating xml nodes with conditions and want to delete a node if it is having no child nodes:

```
<main>
  <tags> 
    <tag></tag>
    <tag>hello</tag>
    <tag>hello1</tag>
  </tags>
</main>
```

I want this output before saving the xml:

```
<main>
  <tags> 
    <tag>hello</tag>
    <tag>hello1</tag>
  </tags>
</main>
```

please ignore node names : if I delete it is deleting but end tag is not removed like `</tag>` is still present after remove:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load($path);

$element = $doc->documentElement;

$elementtodelete = $element->getElementsByTagName('OthersInc')->item(0);

if(! $elementtodelete->hasChildNodes()) {
    $oldelement = $elementtodelete->parentNode->removeChild($elementtodelete);
}
```

Comment: Are you using any libraries to help you manipulate xml in php? Can you show what code you currently have.

Comment: Please add the full source code you have and the XML output you currently get with your source code.

Comment: the above code worked

Answer (score 0):

check this code

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->loadxml('<main>
      <tags> 
        <tag></tag>
        <tag>hello</tag>
        <tag>hello1</tag>
      </tags>
    </main>');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach( $xpath->query('//*[not(node())]') as $node ) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

$doc->formatOutput = true;
echo $doc->savexml();
```

check your desired [output](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/71b530ae1bfc65dfad63ad66bef40888738e4f13)

Comment: i dont have the xml ready , i m creating it and while creating i want to delete the empty node without child

Comment: i don't understand... first create xml then apply above script

Comment: before executing the $xmlDoc->save($path) i want to delete that node

Comment: is it possible?

Comment: added a sample there just want to delete a empty node if present before saving the xml